# How to capture alert box using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, alert

I try to capture alert screenshot but in the screen doesn't show alert box.

For Example:

```
AlertTest
    Open Browser    http://www.seleniummaster.com/robotframeworktest/alerttest.html    ff
    Sleep    5s
    Click Button    name=alert_button
    sleep    10s
    capture page screenshot
    Alert Should Be Present    This is an alert box
    Close Browser
```

If anyone has experience could you help me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my understanding it is not possible to capture the alert with SeleniumLibrary, because the alert in not a part of the page.

We walk around this by using the BuiltIn Screenshot library and the KW [Take Screenshot](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Screenshot.html#Take%20Screenshot).

You could try and consider if it meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're seeing is due to the `Alert should be present` keyword automatically accepts the alert. It happens so fast that if often looks that it never happened. By adding the optional parameter `action=LEAVE` you can check without modifying the behavior. The [Keyword documentation](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Alert%20Should%20Be%20Present) shows other options.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary    

*** Test Cases ***
AlertTest
    Open Browser    http://www.seleniummaster.com/robotframeworktest/alerttest.html    chrome
    Sleep    2s
    Click Button    name=alert_button
    Alert Should Be Present    action=LEAVE    text=This is an alert box
    Handle Alert    action=ACCEPT
    Close Browser
```

Although this will solve your: I don't see the Alert part of the problem, you will run into the next one. Taking a screenshot using SeleniumLibrary will not work because of the now present Alert. As suggested earlier, this can be taken care of by the [Screenshot Library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Screenshot.html#Take%20Screenshot) keyword [Take Screenshot](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Screenshot.html#Take%20Screenshot) .

Please read the [Using with Python](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Screenshot.html#Using%20with%20Python) section carefully as this library depends on Operating System specific Python modules.

Comment: I think the problem is alert box in not caught in the screenshot but not in the assertion keyword of alert box.and this answer is no where around at what OP expects.

Comment: @A. Kootstra  I think it's not because of it's so fast but the alert is in not a part of the page then it made me cannot capture the alert box.

Comment: When following the code example provided, then this is the first issue you will run into. As highlighted in the added section that this will then cause the second problem.

Comment: @A.Kootstra Thank you for your help, Now I use ScreenCapLibrary and edit some python code about screen name for work together with keyword 'Capture 
Page Screenshot' of SelenuimLibrary. But It has a little bit problem because of Test library for taking screenshots on the machine.

Comment: @SawitreeCha it seems to me that this is a different problem from the one in this question. For this reason I recommend creating a new question and providing a complete code example there.